# How can I get data between two date using the format of Date.now

Tags: mongodb

I want to get the data between 2 dates in Mongodb. The format of the date is the 'Date.now' function. Ex :

```
productTimeStamp: '2018-09-29 08:49:20.953'
```

How can I make a query using this date format?

Comment: `Date.now()` returns milliseconds and not `'2018-09-29 08:49:20.953'`

Comment: Sorry for the typo. it is 'Date.now'. I made a mongoose schema and set the default value as 'Date.now'. This is the schema:     productTimeStamp: {
        type: Date,
        required: true,
        default: Date.now
    }

Comment: Sir? Can you help me figure out the solution?

Comment: Rather than using Date.now(), which returns the number of milliseconds, use `new Date()`, which returns a Date object representing the current time. This should work with the Mongoose schema definition.